# Method references in Camel routes

Tags: apache-camel, method-reference

Is there a way to use method references in Camel routes? :

```
from(X).bean(instance::method)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi. As far as I know, It's not possible with "bean". You can find more information through the JavaDoc here: http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/model/ProcessorDefinition.html#bean(java.lang.Class) and more examples here: http://camel.apache.org/bean-language.html. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways you can do this.  As CookieSoup mentioned, you can use the [bean binding](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html)s like this `bean(Instance.class, "method(String)")`.

Or you can use camel [Processors](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html) and Transforms.  There's an example [on github](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-java8/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/example/java8/MyApplication.java) of how to use this (you'll need Camel 2.18.0 or greater).

```
class SomeClass {
    public void method(String body) {
    }
    public String methodWithReturn(String body) {
        return body;
    } 
}


.processor
    .body(String.class, instance::method)
.translate
    .body(String.class, instance::methodWithReturn)
```

Note, [processors](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.22.1/org/apache/camel/builder/ProcessClause.html) are consumers, whereas [transforms](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.22.1/org/apache/camel/builder/ExpressionClause.html) are functions that return a transformed message body.

Comment: Thanks, your answer contains some interresting points that were new to me